# How to query if the name of an item in a list exists in another list in JMESPATH via Az CLI

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath, azure-container-apps

Creating a bash inline script within a pipelineI'm trying to solve an issue where I have the very rare chance a revision with no label in a containerapp stays active during a pipeline build.

I would like to be able to get the names of active revisions then query ingress traffic data with outputs labels and then deactivate this anomaly if it exists.

Firstly I get the name of the current active revisions and store them to a variable:

`activeRevisionList=$(az containerapp revision list -n my-containerapp -g my-resourcegroup --query "[].name"`

This gives me as expected:
`[ "revision-name-1", "revision-name-2" ]`

I'd then like to run the following:
`az containerapp ingress traffic show --name aca-orc-preprod-weu -g rg-orc-preprod-weu --query "[?revisionName in ${revisionsList} && label == null]"`
To get any revisions that are active from the first command that have no label which are therefore not in use.

I see theres a contains keyword but unsure how I'd include that.

Comment: Try this command to check active revision in container app : az containerapp revision list -n containerAppName -g resourceGroupName --query "[?properties.active == true]"

Comment: what s the issue here? are you getting any error/exception? not the desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

> `az containerapp ingress traffic show --name aca-orc-preprod-weu -g rg-orc-preprod-weu --query "[?revisionName in ${revisionsList} && label == null]"` To get any revisions that are active from the first command that have no label which are therefore not in use

The below command is only displaying `label`, `revisionName`, and `weight`, so it's not possible to filter `Properties: Active` details in this command

```
az containerapp ingress traffic show -n "Container-app-name" -g "resource-Group-Name"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To fetch the `active revisions` from all the revisions in the container app, you can use the following command.

```
az containerapp revision list -n "contianer-name" -g "resource-group-name" | jq -c '.[] | select(.properties.active == true) | .name'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [Revision Labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions#revision-labels) &
[How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=examples,bash)

Comment: Thank you for this! Will try it out tomorrow. It's not blatently obvious that properties.active is available from revision list

Comment: Looking at this and this is essentially what I done in my first step, I can get the active revisions, by jsut getting 'revision list' as by default it gets only the active ones. But I need to specifically get the active one that has no traffic or label.

So what I'd like to do is store the revision names response from revision list and then get the revision via its revisionName within the ingress traffic request

Comment: Hi @jamessouthall, az containerapp ingress traffic  command will display only 3 parameters so it's not possible to check with this command.